# Where is the location for the mysqlconnector on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, mysql-connector

I want to continue development on my project on Windows. I was doing development on Linux with the following CMakeLists.txt to find my mysql connector:

```
IF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  # Already in cache, be silent
  SET(MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
ENDIF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)

FIND_PATH(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR mysql.h
        /usr/local/include/mysql
        /usr/include/mysql
        )

SET(MYSQL_NAMES mysqlclient mysqlclient_r)
FIND_LIBRARY(MYSQL_LIBRARY
        NAMES ${MYSQL_NAMES}
        PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
        PATH_SUFFIXES mysql
        )

IF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYSQL_LIBRARY)
  SET(MYSQL_FOUND TRUE)
  SET( MYSQL_LIBRARIES ${MYSQL_LIBRARY} )
ELSE (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYSQL_LIBRARY)
  SET(MYSQL_FOUND FALSE)
  SET( MYSQL_LIBRARIES )
ENDIF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYSQL_LIBRARY)

IF (MYSQL_FOUND)
  IF (NOT MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Found MySQL: ${MYSQL_LIBRARY}")
  ENDIF (NOT MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY)
ELSE (MYSQL_FOUND)
  IF (MYSQL_FIND_REQUIRED)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Looked for MySQL libraries named ${MYSQL_NAMES}.")
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could NOT find MySQL library")
  ENDIF (MYSQL_FIND_REQUIRED)
ENDIF (MYSQL_FOUND)

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(
        MYSQL_LIBRARY
        MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR
)
```

I have installed: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html

Can you suggest what kind of changes I need to make to my CMakeLists.txt to find the connector on Windows as well. Currently, I'm receiving the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
```

Comment: Maybe in C:\Program Files somewhere.

Comment: Unrelated but note that mysql connector is GPL; you might want to use mariadb connector instead, which is LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

From the same site you linked, the [Windows installation layout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation-layout.html) page describes where your MySQL installation might be located:

> For MySQL 8.0 on Windows, the default installation directory is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` for installations performed with MySQL Installer. If you use the ZIP archive method to install MySQL, you may prefer to install in `C:\mysql`. However, the layout of the subdirectories remains the same.

You can adjust your CMake code to search a different set of hard-coded paths on Windows:

```
IF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  # Already in cache, be silent
  SET(MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
ENDIF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)

# Check if this is Windows.
if(WIN32)
    FIND_PATH(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR mysql.h
            "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/mysql"
            )
    
    SET(MYSQL_NAMES mysqlclient mysqlclient_r)
    FIND_LIBRARY(MYSQL_LIBRARY
            NAMES ${MYSQL_NAMES}
            PATHS "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib"
            PATH_SUFFIXES mysql
            )
else()
    FIND_PATH(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR mysql.h
            /usr/local/include/mysql
            /usr/include/mysql
            )
    
    SET(MYSQL_NAMES mysqlclient mysqlclient_r)
    FIND_LIBRARY(MYSQL_LIBRARY
            NAMES ${MYSQL_NAMES}
            PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
            PATH_SUFFIXES mysql
            )
endif()

...
```

Of course, you may have to modify the paths in the code to match your specific installation location.

Also, if multiple people will be using this repository in different machines, it is probably best to move these hard-coded paths to a CMake *cache* variable. This way, each individual can modify the cache variable(s) when configuring CMake to fit their specific MySQL installation location, rather than modifying the hard-coded values in the CMake code itself.